# как достать переменную из html кода

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Даны перменные:

```
$input=`<div class='someclass1'>text2</div><div class='someclass2'>text1</div>`;
```

Как получить массив из `text1` и `text2`?

Я использую:

```
$reg=`/<div class='someclass[0-9]'>[a-A0-9]<\/div>/` // регулярка
preg_match_all($reg, $text, $output); // разбиваем строку в массив по регулярке
$delete_array=[`/<div class='someclass[0-9]'>/`, `/<\/div>/`]; // массив на удаление
$output=preg_replace($delete_array, '', $output[0]); // ['text1', 'text2']
```

То есть входную строку разбиваю на массив по регулярному выражению и из полученного массива строк убираю лишнее.

Проблема - приходится подавать в функцию много переменных.

Вопрос - можно ли обойтись без `$delete_array` и выполнить эту задачу за 1 процедуру?

Почитал про регулярки, но не понял как поколдовать над ними, чтобы в `$output` выходили сразу искомые значения, без использования `preg_replace()`

Comment: Что это у вас за диалект php такой? с бэктиками...

Comment: с чем? вы это про символ "`"? php стандартный, ванильный

Comment: Вот только к строкам он имеет весьма отдалённое отношение..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парсить DOM нужно с помощью парсеров DOM.

```
$str = "<div class='someclass1'>text2</div><div class='someclass2'>text1</div>";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
// $result = array_map(function($div){return $div->nodeValue;}, iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('div')));
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$result = [];
foreach ($divs as $div) {
  $result[] = $div->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($result); // ["text2", "text1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать применить следующее регулярное выражение:

```
\>(\w+)?\<
```

[Результат](https://regex101.com/r/Yyqb9D/1)